# Why does _xlfn. appear before formulas in excel 2021 for functions that worked perfect until feb 1st 2023

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office-2021

Since today I suddenly have _xlfn. appearing for certain functions and I get the #name error. It seems to have to do with using new functions in older excel versions.

I just use Office 2021 (Version 2301 build 16026.20146) like I do since I bought it.
Is there something wrong with an update or something??

All sheets with 'new' functions are suddenly useless. I tried updating, restarting excel, restarting PC but I can't find a solution yet.

Please help,!

Comment: I can't find evidence that [LAMBDA](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67) was ever a function for Office 2021.  The documentation indicates it's only a feature of Office 365 (Microsoft 365). I can't even find Office 2021 (Perpetual) build 16026.20146 [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/update-history-office-2021)

Comment: Maybe you were on an insider/preview/beta channel.

Comment: @Ramhound it is the first item of the second table on your link (Retail versions of Office 2021). The lambda function was always in it.
I had a chat yesterday with a MS support engineer and he confirmed that it was a problem in the latest update and it would be fixed in the next update.

Comment: @JeeWee - The LAMBDA function page only mentions Microsoft 365 versions of Office. I also found other references to Office 2021 and users asking when it would get the function

Comment: In my memory it was one of the reasons I bought Office 2021 but you'r right I can't find evidence now that it was intended to be in 2021. The support engineer mentioned also something about being a mistake that it was. But It certainly was because I made a lot of sheets with that function. Maybe because I have professional plus? Anyway they assured me it would be back soon.

Answer (score 1):

As per [this Microsoft document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/issue-an-xlfn-prefix-is-displayed-in-front-of-a-formula-882f1ef7-68fb-4fcd-8d54-9fbb77fd5025) the error appears when the workbook contains a function not available in your Excel version. The only solution is to remove unsupported functions (or updating your Excel).

Comment: Like I said, I've read that. The point is; just like yesterday I use Office 2021 with the same sheet and formulas working yesterday and not working today.

Comment: @JeeWee - What's the function? [I had a formula that use `CONCAT` I notice it changed to `CONCATENATE`.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/concatenate-function-8f8ae884-2ca8-4f7a-b093-75d702bea31d)  Office 2021 is updated monthly. You will have to determine what the correct function name is and use that instead. I went from a newer version of Office to an older version of Office, the advice is the same, determine what the proper function name is and use that.

Comment: The function that gives the most problems right now is LAMBDA, how can I find out what the function is now? I did not find any mentioning of this function being renamed or removed from office 2021.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that I also had the LAMBDA function in Excel 2021 (not Office 365) and used it up until a few weeks ago but it's gone now. Even updating to version 2302 did not bring it back - it is showing as unsupported